# Preview layout missing from android studio after installation

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

I have just installed android studio after a windows installation, and now i cant find preview window. i tried going view-> tool windows , but i dont have preview option.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hit `CTRL+SHIFT+A` and search for "Preview" and then hit enter. It should show up.

Comment: uhm and also on the screenshot you're in a Java file. There's no preview there. Go into the layout and it should appear.. Moj Milance :D Now I notice the app name and see that you're from Serbia :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new XML and open it. It may not appear until preview mode its needed.